# htaccess - redirect requests to default page on one domain to a file while dont redirect requests from another domain

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess

I have a scenario where im launching a website. Im initially launching the area for contributers to access: sell.domain.com whilst i continue to develop www.domain.com. Both domains will share the same underlying files.

I would like requests to sell.domain.com to not display the base site and redirect to sell.domain.com/file.php which will be the contributor login pages (Hiding the "front end" website still under development).

I would like requests to www.domain.com to display as normal without redirect (DNS currently points elsewhere for www.domain.com so i can use a hosts file to access this domain for development).

When redirecting i dont want every page request (eg sell.domain.com/otherpage.php) to redirect. Only the root? (index.php)

Is this achievable?

Answer (score 0):

Try the redirecting rule

// .htaccess file

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On    
    RewriteRule ^$ file.php [L] 
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 

</IfModule>
```

Comment: This doesnt look to solve the 2 scenarios for different domains

On one domain i want to redirect requests to the root site (sell.domain.com/) to a page sell.domain.com/cb.php

On another domain (www.domain.com) i want to not perform redirects and have the domain function as normal

Any thoughts?